# Code block execution order in PHP

Tags: php, ide, breakpoints

I remember there was shortcut key (probably F8) in Turbo C that showed which codeblock C would execute next.

I wonder if something similar is availabe for PHP? I'm an absoulte beginner and sometime I just don't get how things are executed in PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the debugging support of [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/), it support both [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and [zend debug](http://www.zend.com/community/pdt) extensions/protocol.

You would have to install the PHP extension on your webserver (Xdebug or Zend debug) after you would be able to run step by step you scripts and also see the content of variable in Eclipse PDT.

Also a good start from scratch tutorial [here](http://inkompetent.se/wiki/php/remote_debugging_with_pdt_and_xdebug).

Comment: Great. Any other alternatives or commercial IDE
s that have it built-in?

Comment: Zend Studio have some debugger but that's basically the same things having PDT and the Zend debug extension. So I think PDT is the best option. there is also Komodo from active perl but it's also using xdebug so ...